# Как создать таблицы на SQL?

Tags: sql

Привет! Мне надо создать таблицы и работать с ними на SQL, есть пособия, справочные материалы? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: тебе гугл отключили?

Answer (score 2):

[Документация по SQL](http://www.sql.ru/docs/)

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите документацию вашей базы данных, например: [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html), [PosgteSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html). Или даже в [вики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create_(SQL)#.D0.A2.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BB.D0.B8.D1.86.D0.B0.C2.A0.E2.80.94_Table.5B1.5D):

```
 CREATE TABLE TableName (
   DataValue INTEGER,
 );
```